# Use groovy to load a test resource from my project structure

Tags: groovy

I want to load a resource which is located inside of the /datatest folder in my project workspace. So, the whole file will be /datatest/a.xml .. How do I get the absolute path of this resource that I need in unit tests, since the unit test could be run on any machine I do not want to hardcode it but get it instead from using the classloader ? How do I do it ?

Comment: Is your project workspace on the classpath? Usually not. If that is the case, the classloader cannot see it

Comment: Yes the project workspace is included on the classpath

Comment: You might also check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162100/convert-a-classpath-filename-to-a-real-filename/14162103#14162103)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If it's in your classpath, then this should work:

```
String xmlString = this.getClass().getResource( '/datatest/a.xml' ).text
```

Comment: It is actually a ".lst" file ... for example "a.lst" ... I added it to the compiler resource settings in intelliJ but still no luck

Comment: In that case, it isn't on the classpath

Comment: I hadn't explicitely defined a CLASS_PATH, but found out that the current dir was included in my effective/default CLASS_PATH by running this Groovy one-liner: `this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.URLs.each{ println it }` --then it became clear where I should save files so I could `getResource` to open them later.

Comment: I was missing the leading /