# Convert a classpath filename to a real filename

Tags: java, classpath, filepath

How would I convert the name of a file on the classpath to a real filename?

For example, let's say the directory `"C:\workspace\project\target\classes"` is on your classpath. Within that directory is a file, such as `info.properties`.

How would you determine (at runtime) the absolute file path to the info.properties file, given only the string `"info.properties"`?

The result would be something like `"C:\workspace\project\target\classes\info.properties"`.

Why is this useful? When writing unit tests, you may want to access files bundled in your test resources (`src/main/resources`) but are working with a third-party library or other system that requires a true filename, not a relative classpath reference.

Note: I've answered this question myself, as I feel it's a useful trick, but it looks like no one has ever asked this question before.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a combination of ClassLoader.getResource() and URL.getFile()

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource( resource );
if( url == null ){
    throw new RuntimeException( "Cannot find resource on classpath: '" + resource + "'" );
}
String file = url.getFile();
```

**Note for Windows:** in the example above, the actual result will be

```
"/C:/workspace/project/target/classes/info.properties"
```

If you need a more Windows-like path (i.e. `"C:\workspace\..."`), use:

```
String nativeFilename = new File(file).getPath();
```

Comment: what will this produce if the resource is inside a jar?

Comment: @radai here's an example of the result for a file in a jar: `file:/C:/tools/some/path/jarfile.jar!/internal/path/file.txt`. To find such a file using the answer above, you have to supply a path relative to the jar root - ie. `"internal/path/file.txt"`

Comment: @radai Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025689/filenotfoundexception-when-exporting-jar/12025740#12025740)

Comment: Just plain awesome.  You mention Windows in your answer, but I just ran it on Linux no problem.

Comment: This does not work for filenames with non-URL-safe characters in them - like spaces - because they will be percent-encoded in the return value of `getFile`.