# Save SWT Image to File with Transparency Mask

Tags: java, swt

This is my code thus far

```
ImageLoader saver = new ImageLoader();
saver.data = new ImageData[]
    { toSave.getImageData() };
saver.save(fileName, SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
```

`toSave` is an image that was loaded using the `SWTResourceManager` that is transparent in the program. `fileName` is a string representing the file I want to save the image to (ends with .png)

The result is an image with a black background instead of a transparent background that I want. How do I make the background transparent? I think it has something to do with the transparency mask, but I could be wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SWTResourceManager` seems to be causing your problem. I would not recommend to use it.

Try this code, it works for me:

```
Display d = Display.getDefault();
Image image = new Image(d, "/pictures/Llama.gif");

ImageLoader saver = new ImageLoader();
saver.data = new ImageData[] { image.getImageData() };
saver.save("output.png", SWT.IMAGE_PNG);

image.dispose();
```

Remember to dispose the `Image` when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, and I've read that article. the `imageData.transparentPixel` doesn't work because the transparency type is `SWT.TRANSPARENCY_MASK` and not `SWT.TRANSPARENCY_PIXEL` The code I'm using to retrieve the image is: `Image defaultLlama = SWTResourceManager.getImage(MainWindow.class, "/pictures/Llama.gif");` That is then stored in an `Image` field of an object and retrieved by the function I'm using right now.

Comment: SWT didn't like me calling the `new Display()` constructor (It threw an `Invalid thread access` SWT Error. Instead I used `Display.getDefault()` Then, it didn't accept the filepath I was giving it (/pictures/Llama.gif was in the Classpath, not an absolute path), so I used the solution located at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162100/convert-a-classpath-filename-to-a-real-filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162100/convert-a-classpath-filename-to-a-real-filename) After doing that, it worked beautifully. Thanks!